# Issue in compiling my app in Xcode 6 (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error when compling in Xcode 6. The same code works fine in xcode 5

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/xecck9m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppUniversal-esrzifnzcrxlwmbavvwefvghzghw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppServices.framework/MyAppServices

I explored this folder and couldnt find MyAppServices .

But this compiles without any issues in Xcode 5.

I tried clean build, restarting the app, etc.., still the issue exists.

Comment: The error states "create static library /Users/xecck9.....

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change in my Project target-> Build setting-> Build Active Architecture only and set this Build Active Architecture only to YES.

It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.   I tried changing Build Active Archotecture only to YES. Still the same error exist

Comment: Do you use CocoaPods in your project ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the complete error to your question please